# Why are my UIBarButtons not showing in the navigation bar? (Possible iOS 11 bug?)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

If I perform segues to my VC, the UIBarButtons will show. However, if I programmatically push to the view controller, then the UIBarButtons will not show. Bug is not present in iOS 9 or iOS 10.

This code exists in the first view controller that is presented when the app opens. I am checking UserDefaults to see if I should restore what we are calling an "interaction", and I am programmatically creating the stack. Because of issues I was having with restoring the application state, I have reverted to this method.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ShouldRestoreInteraction") {
            if
                let uri = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "InteractionObjectURI"),
                let id = CoreDataUtils.coord.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: uri),
                let interactionObject = CoreDataUtils.context.object(with: id) as? InteractionObject
            {
                let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Interaction", bundle: nil)
                let interactionCreateOrEdit = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InteractionUnified") as! InteractionCreateOrEdit
                interactionCreateOrEdit.interaction = Interaction(object: interactionObject)
                interactionCreateOrEdit.interactionObject = interactionObject

                if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "RestoreToDashboard") {
                    // restore to dashboard
                    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "MyDashboard", bundle: nil)
                    let dashNav = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
                    let dashboardTVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardTableViewController")

                    self.revealViewController().setFront(dashboardTVC, animated: false)

                    dashNav.pushViewController(dashboardTVC, animated: false)
                    dashNav.pushViewController(interactionCreateOrEdit, animated: false)

                    navigationController!.present(dashNav, animated: false, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    print("Error restoring interaction - did not specify bottom controller in stack")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error restoring interaction - object in core data no longer exists")
            }
        } 
    }
```

However, the weird thing is if I click "Debug View Hierarchy", then the UIBarButtons will display on the phone, but not in the Debug View Hierarchy. If I continue program execution, then hit Debug View Hierarchy again, the buttons will show in the DVH. Additionally, after continuing program execution, the UIBarButtons continue to show in the navigation bar.

Comment: It is not clear from your code where do you get vc3 controller. Looks like you push it twice or something (one from code and one from segue).

Comment: No segues are being performed in my block of code that results in the buttons not displaying in the nav bar. Also I edited my question showing how I'm getting the last view controller where the bug is happening.

Comment: Provide enough context that we can reproduce this for ourselves. I assure you there is no "iOS 11" bug here. It is _your_ bug, and you need to provide enough code so that we can see what it is. For example, maybe you're doing this in a background thread — but you have not shown where you are doing it _at all_ so there is no way to tell.

Comment: @matt I provided exactly what's going on. You don't know for a fact if it is or isn't an "iOS 11" bug. Please be constructive. Now what more information do you need?

Comment: @matt Just saw your edit. Will provide more code.

Comment: Have you filed a bug about this weird behavior of the debugger at http://bugreport.apple.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Mr. Matt was right in his "assurance". Not sure why my code works for previous versions of iOS...anyway solution is as follows:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "RestoreToDashboard") {
 // restore to dashboard
 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "MyDashboard", bundle: nil)
 let dashNav = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
 let dashboardTVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DashboardTableViewController")
 dashNav.setViewControllers([dashboardTVC, interactionCreateOrEdit], animated: false)
 self.revealViewController().setFront(dashNav, animated: false)
}
```